# Getting Access Token from cookies to use with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, cookies, oauth, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Assuming I have a user logged in to Facebook (Cookies are saved in the browser's cache), what is the simplest way to get its access token?
I'm experimenting with Facebook's Graph API, and I don't want to bother with creating an application in order to get access tokens (at least not now).

If I remember correctly, a few days ago I went to http://graph.facebook.com/me on my browser (while being logged in), which redirected me to http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=..., but now I get that instead (and no redirection):

```
{  
      "error":      {  
      "type":    "OAuthException",  
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."  
   }  
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't rely on previously answered questions, since I strongly believe things changed very recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the docs you're going to need are here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

If you just want a single access token for yourself to test some things in the API, you could use the Graph API Explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ) to generate an access token for you for that app and copy/paste it to your code.

Be sure to include the 'offline_access' permission to get a token which won't quickly expire.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't!
You need to create an application to be able to generate an `access_token` (after a successful authentication/authorization). More about this [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: Actually, there is! at [Facebook API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), in the section where they explain about "connections", there are links that include the current user's Access Token. Check it out.

Comment: @JokerThie: I guess these *links* are using the `developer` application to automatically generate the tokens. Or these are generated *specially* for Facebook!